# Query one more existing MSSQL DB from Linux

Tags: django, django-database

I have deployed `django` application running on Linux (Ubuntu) in `VirtualBox`. The `settings` file database section looks like this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

On the local network there is an `MSSQL Server` with database `x` and a few tables. I'd like to create a `view` with `datagrid`, which is able to work with the data from database `x` providing the basic CRUD functionality with possibility of filters.
Could you refer me to the steps with corresponding documentation I need to fulfill? You don't need to go into much detail, only to refer me to what I need to edit and what I should be aware of to achieve a desired result.

Here is my directory tree

```
pd_videowebapp
├── db.sqlite3
├── env
│   ├── bin
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── python3.6
├── manage.py
├── media
├── mysite
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── filters.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── style2.css
│   │   └── style3.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base2.html
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── edit_videos_list.html
│   │   ├── filtered_videos_list.html
│   │   ├── home.html
│   │   ├── upload.html
│   │   ├── user_list.html
│   │   └── videos_list.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── Pipfile
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   ├── style2.css
│   └── style3.css
```

Comment: Is there something you are looking that is not in the existing answer?

Comment: @aaron Yes. I would like to have more precise description with exact commands over the mentioned directory structure. It should work on Linux. It should generate models from database and show the work with datagrid in views with suitable library. In the existing answer the work with routers is especially unclear to me. The answer could be in the form of numbered list showing minimalistic example.

Comment: How is it related to directory structure?

Comment: This question has much to improve. 1. `Needs more focus` `This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.` 2. `Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more` `This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.`

Comment: @aaron OK, the answer can omit the data grid. I may create another question for it. It should outline the working example "how to get data from another database and work with it in views. It should work on Linux and automatically generate models from existing MSSQL DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use MSSQL with Django, first you need to install the `django-mssql-backend` package, run this command in the console:

```
pip install django-mssql-backend
```

Configure the new database in the `settings.py` file of your project:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
    'mssql_database': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'db_name',  # The name of your database
        'USER': 'username',  # The username of the user used to manage the database
        'PASSWORD': '12345',  # The password of the user used to manage the database
        'HOST': 'localhost',  # Or a different IP to locate the server
        'PORT': '',  # Uses the default port
        'OPTIONS': {
           'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',  # Or another version
        },
    }
}
```

You need to define a router that tells Django when to use the new database. A router decides which database to use for a given model based on the app that contains it, not the model name, so we need to create a new app, run this in the console (you can choose the name of the app, but then remember to change the code where I refer to its name):

```
python manage.py startapp mssql_app
```

Adds the app in `INSTALLED_APPS` of `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   # Other apps
   'mssql_app',
]
```

Create a new file to contain the router (maybe in `mssql_app/routers.py`):

```py
class MSSQLRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the mssql_app application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'mssql_app':
            return 'mssql_database'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'mssql_app':
            return 'mssql_database'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'mssql_app' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'mssql_app':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'mssql_app':
            return db == 'mssql_database'
        return None
```

The router works as follows: when the model is contained in `mssql_app` application uses the MSSQL database, otherwise uses the default database.

Adds the router in your `settings.py`:

```py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['mssql_app.routers.MSSQLRouter', ]  # Or another path
```

Now you need to introspect the MSSQL database to create the models with Django, run this command in the console:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database=mssql_database
```

The output of `inspectdb` will contain all generated models grouped together. Copy and paste the content in the file `mssql_app/models.py`.

Note that `inspectdb` is a shortcut, so you should refine the generated models. Read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/) for details on how write models correctly.

Take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/) for all details on how integrate Django with an existing database and at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/) for all details on how use multiple databases.

Now if you want to write views for the models of the `mssql_app` application, simply put them in the `mssql_app/views.py` file, read this [section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/#the-view-layer) (The view layer) of the documentation for details on how create views.

To give an example I will write a view to list the instances of a particular model.

Add this view to `mssql_app/views.py` (replace `ModelName` with the name of your model):

```py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import ModelName

class ModelNameListView(ListView):
    model = ModelName
    template_name = 'list.html'

# Other views
```

Write this url pattern in `mysite/urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path
from mssql_app.views import ModelNameListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', ModelNameListView.as_view()),
    # Other url patterns
]
```

Finally write a template that shows the info of the model instances (put it in `mysite/templates/list.html`):

```html
<h1>List</h1>
<ul>
{% for single_object in object_list %}
    <li>{{ single_object.property1 }}</li>
    <li>{{ single_object.property2 }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No Instances.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This template simply iterates through the model instances and show the values of `property1` and `property2` (I don't know which fields your model has, so replace `property1` and `property2` with the properties name of your model).

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to not to change the `default` database. So MSSQL would be second DB the program uses. In the other anwer was outlined that I need some router, is it true? How to use that router? I don't know which files I need to change.

Comment: Another thing is: Do I need some driver for Linux, for the MSSQL? I have a feeling that I've seen something like it.

Comment: @xralf If you leave SQLite as the default database, Django will not use the MSSQL database. So you need a router to tell Django which database to use and when (the other answer defines a router that always uses the MSSQL database and ignore the other, so if you use that configuration it doesn't make sense to keep the SQLite database). [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/) is the documentation on how use multiple databases.

Comment: @xralf If you want more details you need to clarify why you want to use two databases instead of one, do you want them to store the same information (you will store all data twice) or you want to use each database only for some models? If your project doesn't have any existing models that you don't want to use in the new database, it doesn't make sense to keep both databases. For the question about Linux and MSSQL you should follow [the installation guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15) for your Distro.

Comment: My project has models which map to SQLite database. I'd like to have this information not in MSSQL database. I'd like to preserve the functionality so far, only add the other MSSQL database. MSSQL server is running on Windows, the web server is running on Linux.

Comment: @xralf Ok now I understand your design, I have edited my answer to work with multiple databases. I don' t think you need particular Linux drivers for MSSQL in your scenario.

Comment: I will try it during a day. So far, I had to install `sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev` before `pip install django-mssql/backend`

Comment: `python manage.py inspectdb --database=mssql_database` ended with erro message `django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
`

Comment: I tried [https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/526#issuecomment-433734716] but didn't helped.

Comment: @xralf Does your linux machine have installed the `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server`? If the driver is already installed check the version, maybe it' s not 13. If the driver is not present try to [install it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#13) (remember you need to install the version 13).

Comment: And what if there is not ODBC 13 for Ubuntu 18.04 (my version) may I install ODBC 17?

Comment: @xralf Yes i will update my answer to be compatible with ODBC 17.

Comment: @xralf Ok. Meanwhile I have updated my answer to be compatible with ODBC 17 (I have changed only the settings of the database).

Comment: I connected successfully to the database and inspected the db. Now I tried `mssql_app/views.py:

from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Tblvyroba

class TblvyrobaListView(ListView):
    model = Tblvyroba
`

Comment: and `from django.urls import path
from mssql_app.views import TblvyrobaListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', tblVyrobaListView.as_view()),
]`

Comment: it ends with error 500. Shouldn't I make some migrations or something before restarting apache2?

Comment: @xralf You should provide also a template in your view: `from django.views.generic import ListView from .models import Tblvyroba  class TblvyrobaListView(ListView): model=Tblvyroba template_name='your_template_name'`. If it does not work checks the logs to have more info about the error.

Comment: And the template 'your_template_name' can be located in mysite/templates? Could you write some minimal template to show something from the mssql database? I'm determined to accept your answer, but for completeness, if you have time for it. I'm new to django.

Comment: @xralf You can put your template in `mysite/templates` if you have configured your settings correctly (if your existing templates work correctly then your settings are okay). I will update my answer with a better view example.

Comment: @xralf I have updated my view example, it you want more examples go [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/).  [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/#the-template-layer) you find the documentation on views.

Answer (score 1):

In general you specify settings like `host`, `port`, `database_name` etc. in `settings.py`.

On pipy is driver package [django-mssql-backend](https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/) for mssql connections. It provides a good README.md where you can read more.

---

In general, if you want to set mssql-server as default database, replace the default configuration with the mssql-config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': "sql_server.pyodbc",
        'NAME': "DB_NAME",
        'HOST': "127.0.0.1",
        'PORT': 1234,
    }
}
```

If you want to add the mssql-server as a new database, you need to specify this as a new entry in the `DATABASES`-configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'mssql': {
        'ENGINE': "sql_server.pyodbc",
        'NAME': "DB_NAME",
        'HOST': "127.0.0.1",
        'PORT': 1234,
    }
}
```

If you add the db as a new entry you need specify a `DatabaseRouter` to route the queries to the correct database. You find a good overview to that on the offical django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/).
Add the `DatabaseRouter` in `settings.py` like this:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.MSSQLRouter']
```

Now create a new app (you need to specify the app_name in your newly created router) and add models, views and url routings as usual.